# Recover data after ‘sudo dd if=/usr/lib/SYSLINUX/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda1’

Tags: boot, partitioning, data-recovery

An HDD had 2 partitions, one with Windows 10 and other with Windows 7.
I deleted the partition that had Windows 7 on it.
Turns out it had the boot for Windows 10.

I looked up how to make the computer run again.
The universal answer seemed to be, boot from an Ubuntu USB and run:

`sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda`

where `sda` is where your Windows partition is.

I did:

`sudo dd if=/usr/lib/SYSLINUX/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda1`.

The computer still wouldn’t boot.
But, previously, I was able to see the Windows 10 partition.
Now I see an unknown partition.

Testdisk says the file system is broken.

P.S : Sorry if I’m being unclear or unspecific. Essentially, my question is:

How do I retrieve a folder from an NTFS partition I’ve overwritten with `sudo dd if=/usr/lib/SYSLINUX/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda1`?

Comment: You didn't mention anything on-topic; we don't support windows of any version sorry, only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic   Your `dd` looks wrong to me?  MBR is the first 512 bytes of the disk, not a partition on the disk, however I don't see an on-topic question.

Comment: Testdisk also offers to fix it too doesn't it?

Comment: You accidentally overwrote the first bytes of your partion (`/sda1`) instead of the drive's MBR (`/sda`). If testdisk was unable to recover the partition table then see [my answer using testdisk to recover files or folders from a corrupt drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Comment: The answer to your question depends on what backups you have.  By wrongly writing the MBR into a partition (sda1) you overwrote data that was on the start of sda1 (the significance of that will depend on file-system that is/was there).  Easiest fix is to start again & restore whatever backups you have. Did you make a backup of what you overwrote to be safe? so you could undo the `dd` command if you got it wrong? (as you did, eg. a `dd` command to save that data before your specified `dd` so if wrong, it could be reversed?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Takkat – it took many hours, and one file didn’t copy at all – I mean, I’m sure it would but it was taking so long I thought it would be easier to download it again so I just aborted the operation myself – but I ended up with all boss’ data on my laptop, created a new partition table instead of the corrupted one, and installed the system. Maybe it was still possible to restore the file system as it was before I dd’d it, but it was just more efficient to extract necessary data and install the system anew than to figure out how to revert the dd. Thank you.

P. S. also, WinEunuuchs2Unix – no, it doesn’t. It literally just says ‘Can’t open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged’. That’s it.